# Error:There was an error applying sql script to database error , Error:1064 check Mariadb server manual for correct syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

hey this is my sql which was working fine before but accidentally i deleted the table and re creating this again is showing me with this error.
can any one help me out please

```
    CREATE TABLE `project`.`viewtable` (
  `contact` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `age` INT NOT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ms` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `kids` INT NOT NULL,
  `religion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `qual` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `img` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  `ht` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `wt` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `wrkp` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `comp` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `addr` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `diet` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `wrkpl` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `sal` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact`),
  INDEX `email_idx` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `email`
    FOREIGN KEY (`email`)
    REFERENCES `project`.`main1` (`email`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

i am getting the error:

> Error : there was an error applying the sql script to the database.

this comes up when i try creating the table viewtable , 
if i try executing the statement directly i get an error saying:

> Error:1064 You have an error in sql syntax check the manual corresponding to ur mariadb server version for right syntx to use near '

the project.main1 has

```
CREATE TABLE `project`.`main1` (
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`));
```

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`` CONSTRAINT `email`     FOREIGN KEY (`email`)     REFERENCES `project`.`main1`' at line 23 SQL Statement: CREATE TABLE `project`.`viewtable` (   `contact` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL,   `date` DATE NOT NULL,   `age` INT NOT NULL,   `gender` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `ms` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `kids` INT NOT NULL,   `religion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `qual` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `img` LONGBLOB NULL,   `ht` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `wt` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `wrkp` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `comp` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `addr` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,   `diet` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `wrkpl` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   `sal` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`contact`),   INDEX `email_idx` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE,   CONSTRAINT `email`     FOREIGN KEY (`email`)     REFERENCES `project`.`main1` (`email`)     ON DELETE CASCADE     ON UPDATE CASCADE) ``

Comment: You cut off the error message right before it got interesting

Comment: Show FULL error message!!!

Comment: I see 2 possible problems - 'foreign key is not properly formed' and 'total char fields length is too long'.

Comment: how do i correct the foreign key problem which u stated @Akina

Comment: Add into the question: 1) FULL error message text; 2) `project.main1` table's DDL script.

Comment: tell me what should i specify more for clear understanding. cause i am new t this platform

Comment: The error message, where you cut it off, points exactly to where the syntax error is. By not including it you're asking us to be the syntax checkers. Workbench isn't compatible with mariadb. Which mariadb version? I'm fairly sure mariadb doesn't have visible/invisible indexes, only columns.

Comment: @danblack how do i know which mariadb am i using

Comment: please help me.

Comment: AFAIK mariadb does not support visible indexes..

Answer (score 1):

You create foreign key using the field which is defined as

```
`email` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
```

whereas the field which you want to refer to is defined as

```
`email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

Of course, the reference cannot be created because the lengths are not equal.

---

Possible solutions:

1. Alter field definition in `viewtable` and increase its length from 70 chars to 100 (preferred);
2. Alter field definition in `main1` and decrease its length from 100 chars to 70;
3. Create additional index in `main1` by the expression `email(70)` and refer to it. Or obtain the same result by altering the constraint definition to

```
CONSTRAINT `email`     
FOREIGN KEY (`email`)     
REFERENCES `project`.`main1` (`email`(70))     
ON DELETE CASCADE     
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

In this case the index mentioned will be created automatically.

Comment: hey even after doing this i got the same error, but i tried removing   INDEX `email_idx` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE, and it worked

Comment: because `VISIBLE` isn't a supported MariaDB syntax. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=366302e11ca6ba2825dc3fc359fca347)

Comment: btw the [MariaDB server manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/) for `create table` as at the previous link.